# Nodejs - Youtube Live Streaming API authorization flow without user interaction

Tags: node.js, google-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-nodejs-client, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am working on a nodejs app that would allow users to live stream videos in a youtube channel owned by the application owner. End user does live streaming on behalf of the application owner. In this case, authorization should be done in the backend application itself (nodejs).

[Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps) - This flow requires user interaction. In my case, it is not required as the channel is owned by the developer team (Application owner).

Below is the requirement

- User clicks "Live Stream" button from the front end application
- A request will be sent to the backend nodejs application
- Nodejs app should create a live broadcast in our youtube channel and send the RTMP details as a response and other info will be saved at our db (whichever is required)

How do I achieve the above? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is this a google workspace account?

Comment: @DalmTo No, It is a general google account. Is there any advantage of using a google workspace account for youtube?

Comment: Not really just a rumor I heard that You could use service accounts with Google workspace and YouTube its just not something I have had tie to test yet.

Answer (score 0):

The only authorization method that is supported by the YouTube api is Oauth2.  What you can do and what I have done in the past is authorize the application once then store the refresh token.  As long as your code has a working refresh token to request new access tokens for it will be able to create your live streams as this user as needed.

A few things to watch out for.

1. Your app must be set to production in the Oauth2 consent for or your refresh tokens will expire in an hour.
2. I have no idea if you can spawn two live streams at the same time from the same user channel.  It's not something I have tried.